# CloudFormation Inside VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I get that I can create resources using CloudFormation, and that I can also create a VPC using CloudFormation, along with the resources inside it.

Can I create a stack, using a CloudFormation template, inside a pre-existing VPC? For example, let's say that I have a VPC for my company, and there is a Services segment, some production segments (private and public), and maybe some Development segments.

I want to define each set of services - Services, production environment, Development environments - with its own CloudFormation template inside the VPC.

Can I do that?

Comment: Using the subnet-id in each resources definition is not enough?

Comment: I didn't know you could!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can either pass the subnet id as a parameter and create resources inside those subnets or pass the vpc id as a parameter and create the subnets and resources inside it.

For example, this template will create an RDS database inside an existing VPC:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/RDS_VPC.template

Comment: Great, thank you. I love the idea of cloudformation - past AWS deployments have been by hand with outside documentation - it is infrastructure management by code, which is very elegant. Just still getting my head around some of the details.

Comment: Could I also e.g. reference the VPC ID and create new subnets that way?

Comment: Sure, just create subnet resources referencing the vpc id param!

Comment: Brilliant. I have always loved the extensiveness of thought around AWS and the extensive documentation, but often the path to what you want is obscure.

Comment: Yes, and cloudformation is full of patterns and tricks. To learn more about it i'd recommend you check out the example templates at http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/ ,  the application management blog at http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management  and the Advanced Operations on AWS class at http://aws.amazon.com/training/course-descriptions/advanced-ops/ .

Comment: Thanks @Julio. I already downloaded all of the templates to my laptop, and will look at the class.

Comment: @Julio_AWS_DevRel by using List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id> we can get the list of security groups in the parameters section. But how can we sort the security groups that are attached to particular VPC?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021670/how-to-get-security-group-list-in-cloudformation

Comment: @naveen-kerati as cloudformation is more a declarative language, computations such as filters and sorts are better expressed outside. I usually do it in a shell script that ends up calling "aws cloudformation deploy" or using a lambda function to create a custom resource (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)

Answer (score 11):

Since this isn't documented very well, and all the examples I've seen (including Julio's) just use a string field prompting for manual entry of the VPC ID, here is the best way.

You can have your template prompt you with a drop-down showing all existing VPCs, allowing you to select one.

Use the AWS::EC2::VPC::Id property in your template:

```
{
  "Parameters" : {
    "VpcId" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description" : "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
    }
  }
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Comment: with your solution we can select the VPC from the region. How can we select the security groups with particular VPC?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021670/how-to-get-security-group-list-in-cloudformation

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I was about to point out it should be List<> but I tested both and your approach works as well.

```
"VpcId" : {
  "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>",
  "Description" : "VpcId Ids"
}
```

Comment: Ah. I see list means that you can enter a list of values when using the type, not that you have a list of available types. So for a single value taken from a drop your answer is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The stack defined in another file is for the master JSON a resource of type stack.
Of course you must tell where to retrieve the other JSON/YML file.

Cloudformation is not easy so I would suggest try with an existing architecture and modify step by step.

[This example](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/data-lake-foundation-with-zeppelin-and-rds/) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a regular thing. I even use an external template as a nested stack usually. This way the template is created in another template and it uses only the references from this vpc template, as you would have with a vpc already created.

One example:

https://github.com/caiocsgomes/template-vpc-cloudformation