# How to get security group list in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to get the list of security groups associated with a particular VPC in cloudformation parameter section.

```
    "VpcId":{
            "Description":"Choose the VPC ID"
            "Type":"AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        },
"SecurityGroupsID":{
            "Description": "Choose availablity zone Availability Zone of the Subnet",
            "Type":"List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>"
            "AllowedValues":*******
        },
```

What should be the allowedvalues..?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible to use special template parameters, I created a small cloud formation template with just **SecurityGroup** and **KeyPair** parameters. When you create a stack using this template using console, it will prompt in a Drop Down to select a Key and a Security Group.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "Security Group Test",
  "Parameters" : {
    "SecurityGroup": {
      "Description": "Name of security group",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::GroupName"
    },
    "KeyName": {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    }
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "Ec2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId" : "ami-ea87a78f",
        "InstanceType"   : "t2.micro",
        "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "SecurityGroup"} ],
        "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should also take a look at [parameters-section-structure.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) specially on **AWS-Specific Parameter Types** section. There are many other Parameter Types that may be of your interest such as Route 53 Hosted Zones and VPC.

I don't think it is possible to lookup for a security group because it doesn't exist an **intrinsic function** exactly for this purpose, but if you create the security groups using another cloud formation script it is possible to import.

From AWS Documentation [intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html):

**Stack A Export**

```
"Outputs" : {
  "PublicSubnet" : {
    "Description" : "The subnet ID to use for public web servers",
    "Value" :  { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" },
    "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetID" }}
  },
  "WebServerSecurityGroup" : {
    "Description" : "The security group ID to use for public web servers",
    "Value" :  { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["WebServerSecurityGroup", "GroupId"] },
    "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SecurityGroupID" }}
  }
}
```

**Stack B Import**

```
"Resources" : {
  "WebServerInstance" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties" : {
      "InstanceType" : "t2.micro",
      "ImageId" : "ami-a1b23456",
      "NetworkInterfaces" : [{
        "GroupSet" : [{"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${NetworkStackNameParameter}-SecurityGroupID"}}],
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : "true",
        "DeviceIndex" : "0",
        "DeleteOnTermination" : "true",
        "SubnetId" : {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${NetworkStackNameParameter}-SubnetID"}}
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

At this moment, the only intrinsic function that have similar lookup functionality (but for availability zones) you are looking after is:

```
{ "Fn::GetAZs" : "region" }
```

That can be used in your create SecurityGroups template.

Comment: Thank you. But I have two VPC in a region and in each region I have two security groups already. And when I use List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id> in parameters it is giving me a list of security groups from both the VPC's.So how can I have condition in parameters section in cloudformation to select already created security groups based on my VPC selection

Comment: Today there is no intrinsic function such as GetAZs for getting SecurityGroups for a given VPC, but this might change over time.